# Change what browser is used for displaying office 365 addons

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, word-addins

When developing office 365 addons, some of our installations of Office 365 are using Internet explorer to display the addons, and thus debugging is done using the F12 tool. Some of our installations are using Microsoft edge and can be debugged using the Edge developer tools.

Now my question is, how can we make sure everyone uses Edge to display the addons? Internet explorer is causing some issues with our development builds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control this. The browser that is used is determined by the platform, OS version, and Office version. For a mapping of versions to browsers, see [Browsers used by Office Web Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).

Comment: We fixed the issue by upgrading all development machines to the newest version of windows, which causes Office to use edge, problem solved :).